# Are "done" and "made" interchangeable in this context?

Tags: word-choice, past-participles

I was writing an abstract of an article and started highlighting the advances in a field of knowledge, so I wrote:

> "Over the last 10 years, huge advances have been **done** in the areas of..."

Then, when I was proofreading, I thought that I should use **made** instead. But searching in the internet, both forms are found.

Are they interchangeable in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Advances have been done" sounds quite wrong to me. A check on google ngram viewer shows "advances have been made" is about 1000 times more common (if I've counted the zeros correctly).

It's possible that it's a regional variant, I suppose.

[Google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=advances%20have%20been%20done%2C%20advances%20have%20been%20made&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadvances%20have%20been%20done%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadvances%20have%20been%20made%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cadvances%20have%20been%20done%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadvances%20have%20been%20made%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

Since "advances" in that context means to "make progress", or "make improvements", so I'll stick with **make**.
Also, yeah, **do** sounds wrong.

As a side node, I went down the rabbit hole of "advances" vs "advancements", and it seems that **advances** is more used. [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=advances%20have%20been%20made%2C%20advancements%20have%20been%20made&corpus=26&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadvances%20have%20been%20made%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadvancements%20have%20been%20made%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cadvances%20have%20been%20made%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadvancements%20have%20been%20made%3B%2Cc0)